# Unable to establish connection between Switch in Mininet and ONOS Controller. Switch getting disconnected after new connection

Tags: mininet, onos

I am running **ONOS 2.7.0** on **Ubuntu 18.04**. I am getting a warning Switch Connected in log and then suddenly switch disconnects, hence I cannot do ping from one host to other even after activating forwarding and openflow on CLI. Here is the ONOS log.

14:28:08.940 INFO  [MeterManager] Configured. PurgeOnDisconnection is disabled

14:28:08.941 INFO  [MeterManager] UserDefinedIndex is disabled

14:28:09.430 INFO  [ContextHandler] Started HttpServiceContext{httpContext=WebAppHttpContext{org.onosproject.onos-apps-dhcp-app - 216}}

14:28:09.485 INFO  [ContextHandler] Started HttpServiceContext{httpContext=WebAppHttpContext{org.onosproject._onos-gui2-base-jar - 198}}

14:28:09.538 INFO  [ContextHandler] Started HttpServiceContext{httpContext=WebAppHttpContext{org.onosproject.onos-rest - 197}}

14:30:46.005 INFO  [ServerUserAuthService] Session onos@/127.0.0.1:56670 authenticated

14:31:32.784 INFO  [OFChannelHandler] New switch connection from /127.0.0.1:56918

14:31:32.888 INFO  [OFChannelHandler] Switch disconnected callback for sw:[/127.0.0.1:56918 DPID[?]]. Cleaning up ...

14:31:32.888 WARN  [OFChannelHandler] no dpid in channelHandler registered for disconnected switch [/127.0.0.1:56918 DPID[?]]
ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[localhost]:8101"

This log is from when I try connecting mininet by *sudo mn --controller remote* command.

*** Creating network

*** Adding controller

Connecting to remote controller at 127.0.0.1:6653

*** Adding hosts:

h1 h2

*** Adding switches:

s1

*** Adding links:

(h1, s1) (h2, s1)

*** Configuring hosts

h1 h2

*** Starting controller

c0

*** Starting 1 switches

s1 ...

*** Starting CLI:

mininet> pingall

*** Ping: testing ping reachability

h1 -> X

h2 -> X

*** Results: 100% dropped (0/2 received)

For verification I tried the same thing on **Ubuntu 22.04**. There also problem is the same. What am I missing?

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by installing ONOS wih bazel. Doing so, establishes a suitable environment for the ONOS controller to work. Now I am able to ping after enabling forwarding!